# How do I destructure strings in JS using a special character?

Tags: javascript, date, object

I want day,month and year values from the value in an object.

```
{myDate : '12/31/2020'}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
d,m,y = mydate('/')
```

so that d= 12, m=31 , y = 2020 and they are separated using the '/' character

Is there a way to do something like this in JS?

Comment: `let [d, m, y] = '12/31/2020'.split('/')` good enough for you ?

Comment: A simple [Google search](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+split+string+and+destructure) finds many results. MDN has documentation on [destructuring syntax](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [String methods](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#instance_methods). Please see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/4642212).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the string and destructure the resulting array:

```js
const myDate = {myDate : '12/31/2020'}
const [d,m,y] = myDate.myDate.split('/')
console.log(d,m,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const [d,m,y] = '12/31/2020'.split("/")

console.log(d,m,y)
```

Comment: The same answer is posted above.

Comment: @Kartikey i answered before him.

Comment: Also, the question has a possible duplicate.

Comment: @Kartikey spot on.

Comment: @Kartikey, please be careful when reporting duplicate answers. It's entirely possible that both users were typing at the same time, or that an earlier answer can appear in a review queue.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
mydate = "12/30/2021";
var arr = mydate.split("/");
//arr[0]=12
//arr[1] is day
```

Comment: I guess the above posted answers were sufficient. As the user mentioned in the question that he/she wants to `destructure` the elements and not `access` them